# Vue Test Utils Multiple input emits reset value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

So I've created a vue component and I am using vue test utils to test it. The component allows a user to upload a file which updates an array which is emitted through the input (code shown below) that the user can then access. A new file upload will add to the array and not replace.

What's meant to happen:

I upload the first file and the emitted input event shows that one file; I then upload the second file and the emitted input event shows that file and the first one.

What does happen:

I upload the first file and the emitted input event shows that one file; I then upload the second file but the emitted input only shows the second file.

I'm not sure what is going on here as when I run tests in my browser and console the computed files I see that both files are in the array after doing the same process that my test is doing. I thought it was to do with it not updating fast enough so I added the wait for the next tick but with no luck. Is this a bug or is there something I'm not understanding about the events in my tests? Thanks for any help.

## Component

```
<template>
   <input type="file" @change="handle"/>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       props: {
          value: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default() {
                return []
            }
          }
       },

       method: {
           handle(e) {
               const files = e.target.files;

               var newFiles = [];

               for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    newFiles.push(files[i])
               }

               this.files = this.files.concat(newFiles)
           }
       },

       computed: {
           files: {
            get() {
                return this.value
            },

            set(val) {
                this.$emit('input', val)
            }
        }
   }
```

## Test

```
it('can add to array', async () => {
    const files = [
      {
        name: 'image.png',
        size: 20000000,
        type: 'image/png',
      },
      {
        name: 'image.jpg',
        size: 20000,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
      },
    ]
    const wrapper = mount(Component)

    // Upload first file
    wrapper.vm.handle({
      target: {
        files: [files[0]],
      },
    })

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input[0]).toStrictEqual([
      [files[0]]
    ]);

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    // Upload second file
    wrapper.vm.handle({
      target: {
        files: [files[1]],
      },
    })

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input[1]).toStrictEqual([files]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what has happened now. When the files array is changed in the component I'm emitting it but I'm not saving it anywhere when normally I would have a v-model saving it. As my tests don't simulate a v-model the computed files set value is an empty array. So I need to set the prop value in order to simulate that, I found that I can add a listener for the input event to update the value.

```
it('can add to array', async () => {
    const files = [
      {
        name: 'image.png',
        size: 20000000,
        type: 'image/png',
      },
      {
        name: 'image.jpg',
        size: 20000,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
      },
    ]
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
        listeners: {
           // simulate v-model update
           input: (val) => { 
               wrapper.setProps({ value: val });
           }
        }
    })

    // Upload first file
    wrapper.vm.handle({
      target: {
        files: [files[0]],
      },
    })

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input[0]).toStrictEqual([
      [files[0]]
    ]);

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    // Upload second file
    wrapper.vm.handle({
      target: {
        files: [files[1]],
      },
    })

    expect(wrapper.emitted().input[1]).toStrictEqual([files]);
}
```

Another way to fix this is to save to a files array in the data of the component then call an update function to emit the new array.